# Remove duplicates with date parameter

Tags: json, python-3.x

I need to compare duplicates ip of a json by date field and remove the older date

Ex:

```
[
{
        "IP": "10.0.0.20",
        "Date": "2019-09-14T20:00:11.543-03:00"
    },
{
        "IP": "10.0.0.10",
        "Date": "2019-09-17T15:45:16.943-03:00"
    },
{
        "IP": "10.0.0.10",
        "Date": "2019-09-18T15:45:16.943-03:00"
    }
]
```

The output of operation need to be like this:

```
[
{
        "IP": "10.0.0.20",
        "Date": "2019-09-14T20:00:11.543-03:00"
    },
{
        "IP": "10.0.0.10",
        "Date": "2019-09-18T15:45:16.943-03:00"
    }
]
```

Comment: how do you get `2019-09-14`??

Comment: What have you tried so far? What was the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity's sake, I'll assume the order of the data doesn't matter.

First, if your data isn't already in Python, you can use [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) or [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) to convert it into a Python object, following [the straightforward type mappings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json-to-py-table).

Then you problem has three parts: comparing date strings as dates, finding the maximum element of a list by that date, and performing this process for each distinct IP address. For these purposes, you can use two of Pyhton's built-in methods and two from the standard library.

Python's built-in [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) and [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) functions (as well as [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort)) support a (keyword-only) `key` argument, which uses a function to determine the value to compare by. For example, `max(d1, d2, key=lambda x: x[0])` compares the data by the first index of the each (like `d1[0] < d2[0]`), and returns whichever of `d1` and `d2` produced the larger key.

To allow that type of comparison between dates, you can use the [`datetime.datetime` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects). If your dates are all in the format specified by [`datetime.datetime.fromisoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat), you can use that function to turn your date strings into `datetime`s, which can then be compared to each other. Using that in a function that extracts the dates from the dictionaries gives you the key function you need.

```
def extract_date(item):
   return datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(item['Date'])
```

Those functions allow you to choose the object from the list with the largest date, but not to keep separate values for different IP addresses. To do that, you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), which takes a key function and puts the elements of the input into separate outputs based on that key. However, there are two things you might need to watch out for with `groupby`:

1. It only groups elements that are next to each other. For example, if you give it `[3, 3, 2, 2, 3]`, it will group two `3`s, then two `2`s, then one `3` rather than grouping all three `3` together.
2. It returns an iterator of `key, iterator` pairs, so you have to collect the results yourself. The best way to do that may depend on your application, but a basic approach is nested iterations:

   ```
   for key, values in groupby(data, key_function):
       for value in values:
           print(key, value)
   ```

With the functions I've mentioned above, it should be relatively straightforward to assemble an answer to your problem.